# Can someone give me an example of a signed binary that overflows without a carry?

Tags: binary

I've searched online, but all the examples I found used carry bits. I'm curious, is there an example that someone could show me where the signed binary overflows with no carry?

Here is the specific question that I'm working on:

```
Write two 8-bit signed numbers that, if added, produce an overflow, but not a carry. (Write the same numbers in decimal as well as binary - truncate the binary to 8 bits, write the translation of
the binary answer in decimal.)
```

And just to clarify my understanding, carrying is when you have something like: 1 + 1 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the maximum possible positive value (which will have a sign bit = 0) and add 1; this will result in the sign bit changing, but there will be no carry.

Comment: So in binary terms, I'd add: 01111111 (127 being the max positive value) and 00000001 together? But doesn't adding 1 + 1 for the digit on the right end result in a carry?

Comment: @Karen yes and at plenty of other positions too, but not out of the end (which is where "The Carry" comes from)

Comment: Ohh, I see, that makes sense. So if they wanted an example that results in a carry, they're only taking about the end?

Comment: @Karen: Typically, in CS, *carry* and *overflow* are used to refer to the number treated as a whole, and not the individual bits.